# argpartsort/partsort of 2D array keeping original array dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large 2D array (e.g. [1000, 100]) that I need to do an element-wise partsort on. I need to get the top n largest items in each row of the array, but I need to keep all items in their locations and replace all other entries with 0.

E.g. for top 3 items per row of a 3x5 array:

```
input:
   [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    [8, 5, 1, 9, 4]]

output:
   [[0, 0, 3, 4, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 0, 0],
    [8, 5, 0, 9, 0]]
```

I can do this slowly by performing a `bottleneck.partsort` to get the top n items per row and then setting everything below the nth value as zero:

```
for row in input:
    row[row < -partsort(-row, 3)[:3][-1]] = 0
```

Is there a faster way to do this? For larger arrays with many rows, this may take a while...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do -

```
n = 3         # Number of elements to keep per row
A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],A.argsort(1)[:,:A.shape[1]-n]] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [38]: A
Out[38]: 
array([[ 1, 85, 59,  1, 67, 33,  6, 61],
       [ 5, 81, 72, 14, 43, 76, 23, 23],
       [67, 49, 76, 22, 58, 66,  5, 74],
       [40, 68, 11, 65, 55, 58, 49, 73]])

In [39]: n = 3 # Number of elements to keep per row
    ...: A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],A.argsort(1)[:,:A.shape[1]-n]] = 0
    ...: 

In [40]: A
Out[40]: 
array([[ 0, 85,  0,  0, 67,  0,  0, 61],
       [ 0, 81, 72,  0,  0, 76,  0,  0],
       [67,  0, 76,  0,  0,  0,  0, 74],
       [ 0, 68,  0, 65,  0,  0,  0, 73]])
```

Comment: What happens if the array contains only negative numbers and zeros? I need to do the same thing, but to sort only the non-zero numbers; this method will return zeros as the highest values...

Comment: @MikeFenton So, let's say one row is `[-84,  77,  30, -48, -78, -51, -41, -68]`, what must be the output then? Consider adding a sample input, output for negative numbers too into the question?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.

`bottleneck.partsort` doesn't like zero values and negative numbers, but it works if I replace zero values with `np.nan`.

input:
   `[0, -1, -3, 0, -5]`

output:
   `[0, -1, -3, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) on `axis=1` and let the [*broadcasting*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) do the for loop:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       [8, 5, 1, 9, 4]])

>>> w = np.partition(a, -3, axis=1)[:, -3]
>>> a[a < w[:, np.newaxis]] = 0
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 4, 3, 0, 0],
       [8, 5, 0, 9, 0]])
```